# To prove that any Linear map $T : \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

To prove that any Linear map $T : \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ is uniformly continuous.

My Try: We know that any linear map can be replaced by a matrix. Let $T(x) = Ax$ where, $A$ is the matrix for the linear map.

$||T(x)-T(y)|| < \epsilon \Rightarrow ||Ax - Ay||< \epsilon \Rightarrow ||A||.||x -y||< \epsilon $.

Thus we choose our $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{||A||}$ so that $||x -y||<\delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A = 0$, then $T = 0$, so $T$ is uniformly continuous in that case. If $A \neq 0$, then given $\epsilon > 0$, setting $\delta = \epsilon/\|A\|$ will make $\|T(x) - T(y)\| \le \|A\|\|x - y\| < \epsilon$ for all $x,y$ such that $\|x - y\| < \delta$. So again, $T$ is uniformly continuous.